# When will the Messiah come?

Tags: messiah

When will  the Messiah come?
What does the Torah
and the Rabbis say about this question?

Comment: Basically, they are saying that everyone who has guessed has been wrong so we don't know. It could be tomorrow or it could be any day during the week except for on the Sabbath or a holiday. Ir could be at any time in the future. We only know that it was not in the past.

Comment: @sabbahillel  I would say whatever you think about this question,many views on it is healty and how It can be linked to the festivals.The question is just too important not to ask.

Comment: maximum of 6000th year of jewish calendar

Comment: Funny, The way I learned it, the Sages, z"l always answered this exact question with, "Today, if you will listen to His voice." (Tehillim 95:7, Sanhedrin 98a)

Comment: @Yaacov Dean Beautiful answer